# select top 5 rows returned by particular query sql server

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve top 5 rows returned by this query. How to do this

```
select COUNT(trippackageID), trippackageid 
from tbl_holiday_booking
group by trippackageID
```

Comment: by "top" you mean "with largest count"? Also, which SQL dialect (do you mean "Microsoft SQL server"? there are other SQL servers out there - Oracle, mySQL)?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying the order, do you want the package with the most bookings or the least?

```
SELECT TOP 5 COUNT(truppackageID) Num, trippackageid FROM tbl_holiday_booking GROUP BY trippackageID ORDER BY Num DESC
```

Comment: Yes i want to display packages with the most bookings

Comment: Thank you very much Chris Diver visit me at www.google.com/profiles/mail2mohanpyare

Answer (score 0):

select top 5 * from....

Answer (score 0):

You Can use

> limit 5

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(trippackageID) as cnt, trippackageid from tbl_holiday_booking group by trippackageID ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Assuming you do, in fact, want to order by the count, descending (large to small).  LIMIT 0,5 starts at row 0, and returns the next 5 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(trippackageID) AS tpi_c, trippackageid 
  FROM tbl_holiday_booking 
  GROUP BY trippackageID 
  ORDER BY tpi_c DESC 
  LIMIT 5
```